# Getting Pandora to load in Opera

Tags: opera, flash-player, pandora

I am using the current version of Opera (40). I have confirmed that the current version of Adobe Flash Player is installed (checked on opera://plugins - version 23). However, when I go to Pandora.com, it gives me a screen telling me that I need to use the latest Flash Player.

Anything to do to make this work? Or does Pandora just not work on Opera?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that Opera was set that plugins would only run in "Click to play" mode.

To change this, go to settings (Alt-P), Websites tab, Plug-ins section and select "Detect and run important plug-in content". Alternatively, you can keep "Click to play" selected, and add an Exception for Pandora (or whatever site it is relevant for).

[image]